# Трефной случай — что это?

Tags: семантика

У этого автора часто встречается слово *трефной* в таких примерно выражениях.

> Ну, разве что в особо трефных случаях, когда требуется провести показательное наказание — вроде Милошевича или Саддама...

Как понимать здесь слово *трефной*?

Answer (score 2):

Выскажу предположение что автор не очень удачно обыгрывает значение:

> трефная, трефное. У верующих евреев - являющийся трефом, не разрешенный религиозными обрядами и потому недозволенный в пищу (в отличие от кошерного). Трефное мясо.
>   ([https://поискслов.рф/wd/трефной](https://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.%D1%80%D1%84/wd/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9))

Достаточно часто используются выражения "кошерный", "не кошерный", в отрыве от исходного значения с претензией на юмор. Вероятно подобным образом и здесь.

Comment: Ссылка недействующая.

Comment: Исправил ссылку

Comment: C учётом значения слова "трефной", которое уже привёл sayfriend, получается, что имели в виду что-то вроде "особо преступного".